# React Js: Cannot access context before initialization

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to create a new architecture in my project using context and I started getting the following error:

[Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ProviderContext' before initialization]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DFhP.png

This is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProviderManager from './Providers/ProviderManager';



export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById("root").classList.add("main");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ProviderManager />
    )
  }
}
```

This is my ProviderManager component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RequestService from "./RequestService";

export const { ProviderContext } = React.createContext({
    test: "test",
  }); 

export default class ProviderManager extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
            loading: true,
            text: "Test text"
        }
    }

    addService = (name = "", service = {}) => {
        this.setState({
            [name]: service
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            loading: false
        })
    }


    render() {
        return this.state.loading ?
        (
            <p>Loading</p>
        ) : 
        (
            <ProviderContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                <RequestService />
            </ProviderContext.Provider>
        )   
    }
}
```

And this is my RequestService component

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { ProviderContext } from "./ProviderManager";

export default class RequestService extends Component
{
    static contextType = ProviderContext;
    
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.context)
    }


    render() {
        return <p>Request Service</p>
    }
}
```

Also, this is my package.js

```
{
  "name": "goldpocket-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.7",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

Can you help me find what the heck I am doing wrong?

Comment: PS: If I put all components in the same file, it works. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here:

```
export default class RequestService extends Component
{
    static contextType = ProviderContext;
    
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.context)
    }


    render()enter code here {
        return <p>Request Service</p>
    }
}
```

Static declaration means that the variable cannot be used by other classes even if they inherit the class properties.
Just removing the static property of contextType should make it work.

Comment: Static variables can only be called through class as class instances cannot use them.
Hence you could do: Classname.variable instead of ClassInstance.variable

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to access it when the app is in the loading state here:

```
    render() {
        return this.state.loading ?
        (
            <p>Loading</p>
        ) : 
        (
            <ProviderContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                <RequestService />
            </ProviderContext.Provider>
        )   
    }
```

Just remove the tenary expression to always return the context, and handle the loading state in a different way (e.g. move it to the main app part.